# Error en construcción de una clase

Tags: javascript, clase, constructor

De nuevo los molesto con la misma función, no se que parte del código se encuentra mal, o en que parte de él me encuentro equivocado

Estoy pasando los test, de los cuales me figuran que están mal todas las funciones. ¿Me pueden ayudar por favor?

```
function crearClaseProfesor() {
  // Crear una clase para construir objeto de tipo Profesor.
  // el constructor debe recibir:
  // nombre (string) , edad (integer) , cursos (array de strings) , certificados (array de objetos)
  // Esta funcion debe retonar la clase Profesor.
}
```

Clase Profesor:

```
class Profesor {

  constructor(nombre, edad,cursos, certificados) {
    this.nombre =nombre;
    this.edad=edad;
    this.cursos=cursos;
    this.certificados=certificados;
  }
  
  addCertificado(nombre, entidad, anio) {
    // el metodo addCertificado recibe un string nombre, un string entidad y  un entero anio y debe agregar un objeto:
    // { nombre: nombre, entidad: entidad, anio: anio} al arreglo de certificados del profesor.
    // no debe retornar nada.
    var certificado = {nombre, entidad, anio};
    this.certificado.push({certificado});
  }

  addCurso(curso) {
    // este método debe agregar un Curso (curso) al arreglo de Cursos del profesor.
    // no debe retornar nada.
    this.cursos.push(curso);
  }

  getCursos() {
    // Escribe una función que retorne un arreglo con los cursos del profesor
    // Ej:
    // persona.getCursos() // retorna ['javascript 1', 'javascript 2'];
    return this.cursos;
  }

  getCertificados() {
    // Escribe una función que retorne la cantidad de certificados que tiene un profesor
    // Ej:
    // persona.getCertificados() // retorna 3
    const a = this.certificados.map((cert) => cert.nombre);
    return a.length;
  }
}
```

Instancia de la clase `Profesor`:

```
let unProfesor = new Profesor('toni',33, [1, 5, 7, 8], [{
  id: 5,
  cursos: 'js1'
  }, {
  id: 8,
  cursos: 'js2'
  },
  {
  id: 9,
  titulo: 'js3'
  }
]);
```

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stack overflow en español. Una pregunta: ¿Que problemas te sale?

Comment: ```this.certificado.push``` Debería ser ```this.certificados.push..```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes dos errores en tu método `addCertificado`:

1. Para construir un objeto en Javascript, debes asignar propiedades (a la izquierda) y valor para esa propiedad (a la derecha), revisa la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Object_initializers) al respecto.
2. En el `push` has escrito mal el nombre de la propiedad de la clase, es `certificados`, no `certificado`.

Por otra parte, sigo sin entender la utilidad de la función `crearClaseProfesor()`.

```js
function crearClaseProfesor() {
  // Crear una clase para construir objeto de tipo Profesor.
  // el constructor debe recibir:
  // nombre (string) , edad (integer) , cursos (array de strings) , certificados (array de objetos)
  // Esta funcion debe retonar la clase Profesor.
}
class Profesor {

  constructor(nombre, edad, cursos, certificados) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.cursos = cursos;
    this.certificados = certificados;
  }

  addCertificado(nombre, entidad, anio) {
    // el metodo addCertificado recibe un string nombre, un string entidad y  un entero anio y debe agregar un objeto:
    // { nombre: nombre, entidad: entidad, anio: anio} al arreglo de certificados del profesor.
    // no debe retornar nada.
    var certificado = {
      nombre: nombre,
      entidad: entidad,
      anio: anio
    };
    this.certificados.push({
      certificado
    });
  }

  addCurso(curso) {
    // este método debe agregar un Curso (curso) al arreglo de Cursos del profesor.
    // no debe retornar nada.
    this.cursos.push(curso);
  }

  getCursos() {
    // Escribe una función que retorne un arreglo con los cursos del profesor
    // Ej:
    // persona.getCursos() // retorna ['javascript 1', 'javascript 2'];
    return this.cursos;
  }

  getCertificados() {
    // Escribe una función que retorne la cantidad de certificados que tiene un profesor
    // Ej:
    // persona.getCertificados() // retorna 3
    const a = this.certificados.map((cert) => cert.nombre);
    return a.length;
  }

}

let unProfesor = new Profesor('toni', 33, [1, 5, 7, 8], [{
    nombre: 'Certificado 5',
    entidad: 'E1',
    anio: 2019
  }, {
    nombre: 'Certificado 7',
    entidad: 'E1',
    anio: 2020
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Certificado 9',
    entidad: 'E2',
    anio: 2021
  }
]);

unProfesor.addCertificado('Certificado10','E1',2022);
console.log(unProfesor);
```